# When I run the command "ng build", I can not enter a route from the browser, only by internal navigation

Tags: angular

When I compile my project with `ng build`, it completes successfully.

and I get a structure like this:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="es" class="thin scrollbar-gris" style="overflow-x: visible;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.51e30e538d2560c1a9e9.css"></head>
  <script src="./assets/lib/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  new WOW().init();
  </script>
  <body  >
    <app-root style="overflow-x: visible;"></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a5dd35324ddfd942bef1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.3eb7881d3a00da6c675e.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.dd86f002a5aef1b13f0f.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.23ac360bc829b49bc07d.js"></script></body>
  </html>
```

but it does not find the libraries, then I change

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

and it works. but the real problem occurs in routes of my application such as this one:

```
 http://localhost/my_folder_compilated/programa/detalle-programa/5cf7d27faa8e180017211754

// this is the route that I have in my app.routing.ts
{path: 'programa/detalle-programa/:programaId', component: DetalleProgramaComponent},
{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
```

everything works fine, but if I reload the page in this route I get the error 404 (not found page), if I browse normally following the links of my application, I do not have any problem.

before compiling I do not have this kind of problems and I could enter this route from the browser.

In summary:

I execute `ng build` and the output is the `code` I put. change `href = "/"` to `"./"`, because it does not recognize the `.js files`. I test this on `xaamp` `(localhost/my_folder_compilated/)`

my aplication is on root folder, for example in xaamp is htdocs/my_folder_compilated and the access in the browser is localhost/my_folder_compilated

what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Depending on your server/host you need url rewrite https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: `{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}` should be the last route in your route file. the `path: '**'` is matching everything on the reload.

Comment: @HenslerSoftware yes, sorry this way, in this example I put it just to be seen.

Comment: @penleychan thanks, but I have not modified anything, I am not sure what to do to correct the problem ... so I do not know what to change or I am doing wrong

Comment: are you using server to host your build application?

Comment: @Xesenix I do not understand your question. but what I have is a project that does not have the problem described. I execute ng build and the output is the code I put. change href = "/" to "./", because it does not recognize the .js files. I test this on xaamp (localhost / my_folder_compilated /)

Comment: ok so you are using server now you probalby are missing build params defining where your application will be hosted check  `--base-href=` and `--deploy-url=` and match them with your routes where you host your app

Comment: @Xesenix thanks for your help, I think we are approaching the solution, but can you explain in more detail what you say? I'm not sure. the only thing that I guarantee is that by default I have not changed any route in my project. that's why I do not know what I should change or put.

Comment: @Xesenix In my original application, if I change the href = "/" to something different, the same problem happens to me when I browse that when I compile.

Comment: when angular builds application is kind of needs to know on what route on server it will be hosted so it fixes some baseHre configuration in templates and probably in other places so for example if you know that your application wil be hosted on `example.com/some/path` you need to tell that to build process via `ng build --base-href='/some/path --deploy-url=`/some/path` or something like that im not sure how to those path should look exactly we setup it long time ago for our apps and didn't think of them much from that time.

Comment: We for example are using them for hosting different localizations of our app like `example.com/en` `example.com/pl` etc.

Comment: @Xesenix in my case I will only use it in the style "localhost /myfolder/" I do not know what I should do. thanks for your answer

Comment: the issue here is your server isn't correctly configured to serve an angular application. There is no other issue.

Comment: If your app is served from a subfolder of your server, base href should point to that folder. In your case `<base href="/my_folder_compilated">`.

Comment: @jal my aplication is on root folder, for example in xaamp is htdocs/my_folder_compilated      and the access in the browser is localhost/my_folder_compilated

Comment: @bryan60 this problem happens me on local.... using xaamp

Comment: Also if the base url of your app is pointing to somewhere other than root then base href should reflect that. Did you try <base href="/my_folder_compilated"> anyway?

Comment: <base href="/"> tells your angular app to look for js files at localhost/ but they are accessible at localhost/my_folder_compilated/ the way I understood.

Comment: <base href="/"> not founds my librarys... but with "./" yes, my problem continue..

Comment: providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}], have you add to this

Comment: @yavg if you are using xamp then you need to configure  the Apache to rewrite the url   its explained  well in this article : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @yavg i see you are using xamp you need to setup `.htaccess` to redirect all routes under `my_folder_compilated` to `my_folder_compilated/index.html` at least for none existing files this way whenever you reload server will ask angular what to do with specific sub path unde angular build path

Comment: @Xesenix I use xaamp locally (I gave the example of what I do locally), but actually I need to fix this to publish it in heroku, using nodejs

Comment: If that will be your only app on heroku I think it would be easier just setup it for heroku as there it will probably be on root of your domain and you wont have any of those problems related to baseHref. And for node js part you will be using express server just setup it to redirect routes to /index.html?

Answer (score 0):

A predefined DI token for the base href to be used with the PathLocationStrategy. The base href is the URL prefix that should be preserved when generating and recognizing URLs.

In your `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}],
```

Comment: thanks, but I am having the same result.. tested on xaamp  with     {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './'},

Comment: Have you implement router outlet

Answer (score -1):

Use { useHash: true } in routing. Refer below example. Make the change in your root routing file.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

This will solve your problem of 404 on refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is a routing strategy problem (to use or not a hash (`#`) in your URL). So you have to fix a routing strategy for your project. You can find information [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles).

If you decide to use the hash: in this case your problem will disappear but you will have a `#` in all you app's urls which is not great for your SEO (crowlers still have problem with hashes).

If you decide to go without the hash, I advise you to add a proxy server like Apache2 or Nginx, to re-direct your requests. For example, the proxy would transform `my-website/link1` to `my-website/#/link1` which would redirect the user to the right sceen and Angular will make sure to remove the `#` again from the URL.

Comment: this is the only way?

Comment: in my knowledge, this is the only way. I have faced the same problem 3 years ago with angualrjs and the way i indicated was the only way to do it easily and I haven't seen any angular progress for this point

Comment: @yavg I believe you are  using Apache server (xaamp mentioned in comment)  in  
 the local computer so need to configure `.htaccess ` for url rewrite . This article will help you :  http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @JoelJoseph  I use xaamp locally (I gave the example of what I do locally), but actually I need to fix this to publish it in heroku, using nodejs